# How to negotiate employer's pre-offer requests for personal investment

Tags: interviewing, negotiation, australia

I am currently interviewing with a company for an interesting position that will allow me to grow professionally. After the initial interviews, the employer is now asking me to study two academic subjects in my own time using books before *considering* an offer. I estimate that such study, beside my current job, will take 2-3 months or more.

The interview included a coding interview in which some of the questions were nowhere close to what I prepared myself for, neither had I come across similar problems in the "real-world". The challenges ended up highlighting that I had not pursued a particular abstract type of knowledge through directed study.

The hiring team "liked me", but they are asking me now to study two subjects, using books, in my own time, before they consider making an offer. This includes not only the broad subject of the coding interview, but a whole new programming language, which previously did not surface as a pre-employment condition. Beside my job and family, doing so would take me 2-3 months at least.

Instead I could simply look for a different position. It would take me only about three weeks of study to prevent a similar scenario from happening again.

Soon I will have another meeting with the hiring boss to discuss the path forward. I am quite invested now, and the position is interesting, so instead of pursuing a different opportunity straight away, I first want to try to negotiate a path forward that gives me some assurance of employment with a reasonable study requirement. My investment should be met with a commitment. Furthermore, multiple months is far into the future for the hiring process and gives a lot of uncertainty. The further the potential employment is away, the higher the need for a formal agreement, unless the period can be reduced.

What kind of arguments/things can I offer the employer in exchange for a formal commitment from their side? I am thinking of things like probation period, reducing the study subjects to one, and studying the other one while employed...

**Update:** There have been a lot of guesses about the employer's intention. Today I had a meeting with two of their top figures, and the plan forward was quite clear: They want me to learn the subject matter of the coding interview, and then re-sit the same. Even though I'm not fully qualified for the position yet, they feel it's worth hiring me for other reasons if I do some catching up, and then receive some training/guidance during the actual employment. It's the first time for them to take this approach, and they pointed out that talent is scarce. They gave me a couple of book references to work through, and will meet with me from time to time to coach me and guide me through the process. Even though employment is not yet guaranteed, it is the expected outcome of the process, which may take about a month.

Comment: i'm sorry, what?

Comment: you want to ask the hiring manager to formalise a mutil-probability process?

Comment: i don't think any of this makes sense, unless your employment situation is quite dire. i'm not sure what they're asking you to study, and do you have a job right now? if you're studying so much just take the AWS exam and get a job doing that

Comment: Probably a mistake to focus on one company that thinks you're not qualified.

Comment: My take: they do like you but they're stringing you along while hoping to find someone with the qualifications they want.

Comment: Can you ask them to present a conditional offer which will become a formal offer on completion of the study and passing of the test? 
I get a lot of people would say just move on but if it's only costing you time (not money) and it's an interesting position- you're gaining knowledge anyway, that's never a bad thing! How desperate are you to leave your current job?

Comment: I think the big question here is whether these areas of study would help you in other jobs, and if you particularly want to work in them? Does this study benefit you, or the company?

Comment: It might be very worthwhile to work for a company that is that interested in your professional development.  Not many are.

Comment: The ***only*** positive thing here is that they "`will meet with me from time to time to coach me and guide me through the process`" - but it doesn't begin to balance out the negative. There are plenty of more fish  in the sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kind of arguments/things can I offer the employer in exchange for
>   a formal commitment from their side? I am thinking of things like
>   probation period, reducing the study subjects to one, and studying the
>   other one while employed...

You can attempt to negotiate anything. And what you are suggesting seem like reasonable choices. I suspect they are unlikely to make a formal job commitment though.

Decide ahead of time how much effort on your part is worth a *chance* at a position, and go from there.

I'm guessing you'd be better off just moving on to a position where you are already qualified. But you might still want to try. The worst they could say is "No".

Comment: This correctly addresses the subject matter of the question, and I am thankful for this insightful answer (to a lengthy question, after all). In the end not much negotiation was required in reality, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky.

**Plan A:** You could form an agreement "if such and such requirements are met, an official offer will be extended". However, this is no good since it has no teeth: if they don't want you they can simply put something wonky in the offer that you wouldn't accept. Even if you do, they can always fire you again 2 weeks later (assuming it's at-will employment in the US)

**Plan B:** Try to get paid for your study and time investment. Have them hire you as a contractor or freelancer and let them pay you XXX$/month. If this results in full time employment, they can recoup all or some of the money by withholding YYY$/month from your salary.

They way to "sell" this to the company is to talk about "shared risk". The study is a non-trivial investment on your part and it seems unreasonable for you to carry the entire risk on your own. If the truly are interested in you, they should be willing to carry some of the risk as well and Plan B is reasonable vehicle to do this. You can play around with the numbers to adjust how the risk is shared, how much of the upfront money the company can recoup and how long it will take to recoup.

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase the question:

> Prospective employer says "I can't hire you right now because of lack of qualifications. When you get those qualifications, we can talk again"

What you are missing is a list of requirements. "Read a book" is a pretty vague one, and sounds more like an excuse to get rid of you while being nice. **Right now they don't want you** for whatever reason, and there is little you can do to change their mind. They are not ready to invest in you more than few hours of meetings time already spent.

If you really like the job, get a list of concrete, measurable items that you need to hit in order to qualify for the job.

That might include:

- passing some certification/test (a la AWS or Oracle certs)
- getting certain degree in local university
- showing ability by being employed in the field X for N years
- join their cult by reading books A and B

Comment: Nice translation!

Comment: Nice translation, but not correct (that may be my fault!). They are happy to keep talking and to keep investing time, and the instructions and requirements are clearer than "read a book" - they are not any books, but specific books for the code interview, that contain the knowledge they see missing. Certifications may be helpful to make yourself more employable in general, but won't help in this matter

Comment: @ig-dev Here, investing time means hiring you, then training. "Still talking" isn't really investing much time. Yes, "read a book" is a mistranslation since it's actually "read *this* book," but the point is that reading it guarantees nothing. If you read and read and read, but still get rejected for vague reasons, how would you feel? If they say "get this cert and you'll be our ideal candidate," you can much more confidently pursue the studies needed

Comment: @ig-dev read "specific books for the code interview, that contain the knowledge they see missing". It is still un-scientific, to my understanding.  How will you know that you read enough of a book? Understand it in enough detail? That is why my feeling is that you need to clarify requirements.

Comment: @ig-dev Unless its on a contract, "Read this book. Get the Job", they are simply waiting for the right person with the right skills to apply for the job. That 2-3 Months for you to read the books is 2-3 more extra months of other job applicants trying to get it. If they were willing to train you, an extra 1-2 months of on the job training would be easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you look for a new job, you take into consideration the cost of applying, the likelihood you get the job, and the benefits of the job.

These guys want you to invest two months of your time not to get a job, but to get another interview. You should be able to take  40 interviews in that time, so that would most likely be a much better investment of your time. And remember, all they promised was a second interview. So I would recommend to let this one go.